# Parameterized dynamic sql returns no results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

From a C# application I create the following parameterized dynamic sql statement as captured by SQL profiler:

Executing this statement returns no results:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT IDWebFormAnswer FROM WebFormAnswers WHERE IDWebform = 55 AND IDWebFormQuestion = 478 AND (ANSWER = ''@answer0'')', N'@answer0 nvarchar(2)', @answer0=N'XL'
```

However, if I simply replace @answer0 with XL in the following, I get 4 rows returned.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT IDWebFormAnswer FROM WebFormAnswers WHERE IDWebform = 55 AND IDWebFormQuestion = 478 AND (ANSWER = ''XL'')', N'@answer0 nvarchar(2)', @answer0=N'XL'
```

I do not understand why this happens? Am I building the query wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a parameter you should not enclose it in quotes. If you do that then the parameter name becomes a literal string. With your code the query search for an ANSWER that contains the value '@Answer0' and there is none.

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT IDWebFormAnswer FROM WebFormAnswers 
      WHERE IDWebform = 55 AND IDWebFormQuestion = 478 AND 
      (ANSWER = @answer0)', N'@answer0 nvarchar(2)', @answer0=N'XL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve already answered it well so I will try and give some tips that I picked up through my several failures while working with Dynamic SQL. Hope it is useful.

First write out your query as such with all parameter declaration

```
DECLARE @answer0 nvarchar(2)

SELECT IDWebFormAnswer
FROM WebFormAnswers
WHERE IDWebform = '55'
  AND IDWebFormQuestion = '478'
  AND (ANSWER = @answer0)
```

Now replace all single quotes with 2 Single quotes (I use CTRL+H, replace ' with '')

```
DECLARE @answer0 nvarchar(2)

SELECT IDWebFormAnswer
FROM WebFormAnswers
WHERE IDWebform = ''55''
  AND IDWebFormQuestion = ''478''
  AND (ANSWER = @answer0)
```

Next Break this query down and encapsulate with leading and trailing Single quotes and integrate with sp_executesql syntax.

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500),
        @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500),
        @ParmValue1 nvarchar(2);

 /* Build the SQL string one time.*/
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT IDWebFormAnswer
                   FROM WebFormAnswers
                   WHERE IDWebform = ''55''
                     AND IDWebFormQuestion = ''478''
                     AND (ANSWER = @answer0)';


SET @ParmDefinition = N'@answer0 nvarchar(2)';

 /* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */
SET @ParmValue1 = N'XL';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                       @answer0 = @ParmValue1
```